# Flask - change the column type in existing database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have following Model in existing db:

```
class Advert(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default = datetime.utcnow)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

I just want to remove unique=True from my Model. How to do that?

Comment: Use the alter SQL statement directly to your database created after removing unique attribute in the code base. Another way is to use a library like Flask-migrate but not 100% sure whether Flask-migrate would catch those attribute changes.

Comment: I do that through flask-migrate and remove this unique=true line in code but flask-migrate dont detected any changes in schema

Comment: Yea, then the only option you have is to run the alter SQL statement directly to your db.

Comment: Then, how to do that directly in my db? Through command line?

Comment: Go inside your database and run a SQL command.

Comment: if you are using MySQL then command should be something like mysql -u root -p

Comment: I use sqlalchemy and sqlite

Comment: How do you access your database in general? Meaning where do you see the data in the database? That is the place that you need to run the SQL command.

Comment: All the stuff with db i use in command prompt. In my shell i import db from my app, then models and do the things

Comment: I think you need to figure out how to access to your sqllite database, where you can make sql queries directly into the db that you've selected.

Comment: Either above or you can create a python script that has something like below. sql_query = 'your_alter_sql_query' db.engine.execute(sql_query) and run the python script.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest using [Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) for the database migration.

Let say if you want to alter the table. Just create an empty scheme migration `alembic revision -m "alter table"`

then you can add the alter here:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

revision = 'xxx'
down_revision = 'xxx'

def upgrade():
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE xx ... ')
    # Add the ALTER query here

def downgrade():
    pass
    # Add the ALTER query here
```